# How to store array in CodeIgniter sessions?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, session

I am calling a controller with method `setActiveId` and store 1 array in session and display after storing by using `var_dump($this->session->all_userdata())` it shows perfectly but in same controller when I print the session in other method say `checkinkingPermission` then the array in session is empty.

Now I repeat all steps with one additional step.

I did store array in session like before and after storing I store one dummy variable in session like this,

```
$this->session->set_userdata('dummy','tesing');
```

and again print using `var_dump($this->session->all_userdata())` it display all session with array and last dummy variable and when check in `checkinkingPermission` then array in session and dummy variable is shown perfectly (it solves my problem but its rough solution).

I want to know did anything  miss or what problem is there that array not save in first scenario (also array is not greater then 4Kb (CI Session limit)).

**Update**

Method from model named connections_model

```
public function setActiveFriend($id) {
    $this->load->model('friend_model');
    $this->session->set_userdata('AF',$id);
    if($id==$this->session->userdata('userid'))
    {
        $this->session->set_userdata('MEOWN',1);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->session->set_userdata('MEOWN',0);
    }
    $this->friend_model->setFP($id); // Calls Here a method that is defined in another model
}
```

Another method that defined in friend_model

```
public function setFriendPermissions($id) {

    $this->session->set_userdata('CFP',array());
    $this->db->where('user_id',$id);
    $locs = $this->db->get('friend_p')->result_array();

    if(is_array($locs))
    {
        foreach($locs as $loc)
        {
            array_push($this->session->userdata['CP'],$loc['perm_id']);
        }
    }
    $this->session->set_userdata('dummy','tesing'); // Important Line
}
```

In above method I set values in session array if I want to see session values in same method  then its set and viewed but the array is empty if I print session in any method of connections_model file.

**Important**
If I wrote this line `$this->session->set_userdata('dummy','tesing');` then session array save and viewd in all methods and if I don't write that line session array is empty.

Comment: For making the question clear, do you say when you store an string in the session it is available in the second method but when storing array it is not?

Comment: when i am saving array in session it will store but not show in other methods but when i store array and also stor some string after store array then the array store permanantly otherwise not

did it clear to you or may i post some code that i use?

Comment: Where did you write load `$this->load->library('session');`?

Comment: like this `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session', 'Common_Library');`

Comment: Do you have check your session life time?

Comment: yes and its enough i think `$config['sess_expiration']  = 7200;`

Comment: Can you show session config?

Comment: `$config['sess_cookie_name']  = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']  = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']  = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;`

I am using the default configurations

Comment: Can you post at least some of your controller code so we can make sure it's not being clobbered somewhere? That's the most likely cause for weird issues like this. Additionally, and this is my own opinion, I recommend using DB sessions. It's not perfect for all cases, but it's a good way to get around a lot of weird issues you run into.

Comment: @Zarazthuztra I updated my question with some code

Comment: You can store your arrays in session using JSON. It is simple

Answer (score 3):

You're not accessing the session data properly:

```
$this->session->userdata['CURRENTFPERMISSIONS']
```

That's what you have. Keep in mind that $this->session->userdata is a function, not an array, that said, try this

```
array_push($this->session->userdata('CURRENTFPERMISSIONS'),$locpermission['perm_id']);
```

Please see the [documentation on session management](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)

I don't recommend using all cap keys for your arrays, as that convention is supposed to be used for constants.

In addition to the above, try changing this:

```
if(is_array($locpermissions))
{
        foreach($locpermissions as $locpermission)
        {
            array_push($this->session->userdata['CURRENTFPERMISSIONS'],$locpermission['perm_id']);
        }
}
```

to this

```
if(is_array($locpermissions))
{
        $tmpArr = $this->session->userdata('CURRENTPERMISSIONS');
        foreach($locpermissions as $locpermission)
        {
            array_push($tmpArr,$locpermission['perm_id']);
        }
        $this->session->userdata('CURRENTPERMISSIONS',$tmpArr);
}
```

Although, the more I look at your code, the more I don't understand why you are going ahead and setting up a blank array in the session structure if it only ever gets populated inside a conditional. May want to re-factor that a bit

Comment: Sounds like the internal session data structure is not being updated even when you pass the array it's holding as a reference. Strange, I'll have to go check the source code on that one. In any case, answer updated.

Comment: thanks :)  yeah i also change like that anyways it helps me and correct to me